# rqt_graph functionality for drake + LCM

Tags: drake, lcm-data-marshalling

I'm working with drake and LCM messaging in a robotic manipulation context and would like to know if there exists an LCM functionality similar to rqt_graph for ROS, which visualizes inputs and outputs to different nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lcm-spy ships with lcm and has basic scope-type plotting.

Comment: If you are also visualizing diagrams themselves, you use Drake System's graphviz functionality: [C++ API](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#a588e4f7454694f04b4b654d154f170f3), [matplotlib API](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/fa70f9c09829cb50979a771f20077239f348b997/bindings/pydrake/systems/drawing.py#L40)